# Conditional probability density function

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, conditional-probability, bayes

Let $\theta$ be the parameter of the probability density function $f(x)$.

If it is mentioned that $f(x|\theta)$ be the conditional probability density function, then what does $f(x|\theta)$ mean?

Most often we don't know the value of $\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

> what does $f(x|θ)$ mean?

It's $f(x)$ given that the value of the parameter $\theta$ is specified at some value.

e.g. "the density of height, given that the mean height is at 175cm", that kind of thing.

You don't have to know the mean height is actually 175cm ... if you like, it's a counterfactual. I can also discuss the distribution of how much money would be in my wallet on a Friday, even though it's Wednesday.

Comment: If we can guess a value of $\theta$, then why do we need to draw sample and estimate the parameter $\theta$ ? Is that for checking whether we did a wise guess of $\theta$ ?

Comment: Who said anything about guessing? If I say "what's the upper quartile of the amount of rain on a day when it rains?" but it's not raining today, it doesn't mean "I guess it'll rain today". I already *know* it's not raining (that's the counterfactual), but I want to know *what the 75th percentile would be when it does*. That's the upper quartile of the conditional distribution.

Comment: I apologize. I have not understood yet. If i say "the density of height given that the mean height is at $175$cm", then how did i have the value $175$cm if i don't know the mean height is actually $175$cm. Is it from relevant prior study ? If my study is first in that field, then how can i have the value?

Comment: It can be for any reason, from any source - that depends on what you're computing the conditional distribution for, but is of no relevance when it comes to finding the conditional distribution. In some cases you might evaluate something over all possible conditional distributions, for example, or over some subset of possible values.